# Move Product Variations (woocommerce_before_variations_form) above woocommerce_single_product_summary

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm a newbie here.

I am trying to move Product Variations, which I believe are in 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', on Single Product Page to above the Product Title, Price, and everything else in the 'woocommerce_single_product_summary'. See Image.

[image: Image of Woocommerce Hooks on Single Product Page]

The code I have tried is:

```
function move_variations(){ ?>
  </div>
  <div class="summary entry-summary">
<?php }
add_action('woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'move_variations', 1);
```

Placed at the bottom of my child theme's funtion.php file.

It is moving the Variations and everything below them (buy buttons, description) to below the main product image.

Anyone know what I need to fix?

I have tried different priorities and div classes, but am not achieving desired result.

Comment: Hoping for any suggested edits to code snippet. Thank you!